# Open other Excel files with password once main worksheet is opened

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm working with 5 different worksheets. 1 main worksheet and 4 reference worksheets(with links on the main file) which require a password to open. I made a code to open the 4 reference worksheets as soon as the main worksheet is opened but when I did that, it still prompts me to enter the password. What happens now is that the main file + the 4 reference files open right away but the prompt still shows up.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j1") _
        & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j2"), Password:="*****"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j1") _
        & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j3"), Password:="*****"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j1") _
        & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j4"), Password:="*****"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j1") _
        & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("j5"), Password:="*****"
End Sub
```

And I get this prompt when I open the main file:

[image]

What I would like to happen is for the prompt to go away of if there's a VB script to enter the password for the prompt, that'd be okay.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to post your code as text, not a picture. Some of us are in environments where imgur and social media are blocked; some of us are visually-impaired and use a screenreader; some of us are the the kind of people who won't participate in a discussion that's set up to exclude visually-impaired people; and some of us won't look at code we can't copy-and-paste into a test function...

Comment: I have deleted my answer being it not what you're looking for. However, still I suggest you to start looking into the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it. I'm very new to VBA and I'm still learning the ways.

Comment: You haven't described the situation very clearly. When you manually open the "main" workbook, you will always be prompted for the password. Are you opening the main workbook manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to open protected worksheets within the workbook your code should be something like this:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Unprotect "Your Password"
```

Otherwise I thought open workbook needs some ()

```
Workbooks.Open(Filename:= "file.xls", Password:="ABC")
```